# Whats the Difference Between a Chrome Extension and Workspace Marketplace App?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-workspace

Can someone please explain to me the difference between a Chrome Extension and a Google Workspace Marketplace App?

I have tons of experience in Chrome Extensions, but I don't understand the difference between that and a Workspace App. Like, how does development work? Can someone please give me some documentation on how to make one?

Thanks.

I have tried following the very little documentation on development of a Google Workspace application.

Expecting some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain both of them in simple terms:

**Chrome Extension:**

Think of a Chrome Extension like adding some cool tricks to your internet browser (like Google Chrome) to make your online experience more fun. It's like giving your browser extra abilities, such as stopping annoying ads, capturing screenshots, or changing how web pages look.

**Google Workspace Marketplace App:**

Now, picture building something that not only works in your web browser but also cooperates seamlessly with Google's apps like Gmail, Google Drive, and Calendar. It's like crafting a special tool that assists you in getting work done or collaborating with others within Google's world of productivity apps.

So, in a nutshell, Chrome Extensions jazz up your web browser, while Google Workspace Marketplace Apps are like supercharged tools that easily fit into Google's suite of apps for work and teamwork.

Answer (score 0):

Workspace Addons are better integrated with the Google ecosystem. You can securely call the APIs very easily and add some interfaces only in the places you are allowed (there are pre-defined interfaces, and actions you can use).

You are also limited by the componentes you can use. You don't have access to HTML or to all the Material UI components. You can visit this page to have an idea: https://gw-card-builder.web.app/

Example here:

[image]

There are also Editor addons that can be added to the Docs part. You can use AppScript for this one:

[image]

On the other hand Chrome extensions are more flexible ,you can manipulate the browser's DOM. This mean you can inject things on the screen, basically put anything, anywhere.

The con is you rely on the HTML nodes properties (e.g: a div id) so if google changes how HTML is rendered then you will have to adapt your extension.

I think at this moment the extension is worth the risk. Workspace addons are limited and poorly documented.